# Should I find consulting contracts before or after moving to the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, job-hunting

I'm seriously thinking about moving from Canada to the UK for two years, to work as an IT consultant. I want to get a contract before leaving Canada, but pretty much every recruiter I talked to seem to suggest me to opt for a work sponsorship instead.

Should I get contracts before or after leaving, considering the fact that most recruiters tell me to get sponsorship instead since I'm not already in the UK? Is it because companies do not want to do contractual business with someone still abroad, or is there another reason?

Comment: Are the agencies (recruiters) suggesting this because of your visa status?  In other words, are you sure you're allowed to work in the UK as a contractor/consultant?

Comment: Yes, the **Tier 5 (Youth Mobility Scheme)** visa allow self-employment.

Comment: Hey TheCanadian, and welcome to [expatriates.se]! I'm a bit confused by your question as-is. You seem to be asking about types of sponsorship which would be separate from how to secure an income, and it isn't clear how these relate to your discussion with the recruiter. Could you [edit] your question to clarify your situation and the discussion with recruiters better? It will help you get better answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RobHoare This visa allow to work as a consultant.

Comment: You're asking a rather subjective question. Everyone has different experiences, and some swear by getting jobs before they move, while others (eg myself) are happy to wing it.  Could you check [help] and edit your question to clarify what you want answered, rather than soliciting opinions? Thanks!